# Name of Equation $Q = \Delta P / R$

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology, flow, bernoulli-equation, viscosity

A very fundamental equation in understanding fluid flow is $Q = \Delta P / R$. When the flow is through a cylindrical pipe of constant radius, $R=8\eta L/\pi r^4$ can be substituted to give Poiseuille's Law. This is basically the first think you learn after Bernoulli's Equation. However, I cannot remember the name of the first equation. All the online resources I can fine mention the first equation, but them immediately introduce Poiseuille's Law and don't state the former equation's name.

Comment: $Q=\frac{\Delta P}{R}$ is usually just referred to as "the basic flow equation". Is that the equation you are asking about (your wording is ambiguous)? The most fundamental equations in fluid dynamics are the _continuity equation_ and the _Navier-Stokes equations._

Comment: It's also a type of very broad **flux** or **kinetics relation**; the flux of something scales with the driving force and the generalized conductance. Heat? Conductive flux scales with the temperature difference and thermal conductance. Charge? Current scales with the potential difference and electrical conductance. Mass? Diffusion scales with the concentration difference (even more generally, the chemical potential difference) and diffusion coefficient. Here, a pressure difference provides the driving force pushing fluid flow against a resistance.

Comment: I call it the pressure drop-flow rate equation for laminar flow.